# jstoxml converter module in node not parsing data in correct structure

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, npm

I am trying to convert a JSON object to XML in my Node js service with jstoxml module. My input structure is:

```
{
    "user": "505723c5750c1fa2177682ed",
    "uri": "http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items",
    "items": [
    {
        "uri": "http://localhost:3000/items/1"
    },
    {
        "uri": "http://localhost:3000/items/2"
    }
    ],
    "info": "blah."
}
```

My expect result is:

```
<user>505723c5750c1fa2177682ed</user>
<uri>http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items</uri>
    <items>
        <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/1</uri>
    </items>
    <items>
        <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/2</uri>
    </items>
<info>blah.</info>
```

Result i am gettings is:

```
<user>505723c5750c1fa2177682ed</user>
<uri>http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items</uri>
    <items>
        <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/1</uri>
        <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/2</uri>
    </items>
<info>blah.</info>
```

If anyone faced similar issue, plese help me. Is there any other npm node package for getting this in expected structure?

Thanks

Comment: thats an exact json to xml conversion, why you want it to be different..

Comment: Naeem thanks for the comment. i need the result in the format of my expected result. Is there any way it do so?. or what i change i need to do in json to get the result as i expected??

Comment: Naeem.. Try this online tool in [utilities-online.info](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VHhpm9JlH1Z). this is giving me the result as i expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for my question. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/) you can get it. [this](https://x2js.googlecode.com/hg/demo.html) is an online demo. By exporting code they provided we can achieve it,

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix), an open-source JavaScript library for XML<->JS conversion. Jsonix is available for Node.js (see [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsonix)).

[Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) can convert between XML and JSON (in both directions) based on a *mapping*. The mapping gives you the flexibility when transforming between JSON and XML. This may be what you need here.

---

I'll let the code speak. Here's a demo case for your JSON->XML conversion:

- https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/tree/master/nodejs/demos/user

[Mapping](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/master/nodejs/demos/user/jsonix-demo-user.js):

```
var Mapping = {
    name : 'Mapping',
    typeInfos : [ {
        localName : 'Data',
        propertyInfos : [ {
            name : 'user'
        }, {
            name : 'uri'
        }, {
            name : 'items',
            collection : true,
            typeInfo : '.Item'
        }, {
            name : 'info'
        } ]
    }, {
        localName : 'Item',
        propertyInfos : [ {
            name : 'uri'
        } ]
    } ],
    elementInfos : [ {
        elementName : {
            localPart : 'data'
        },
        typeInfo : '.Data'
    } ]
};
module.exports.Mapping = Mapping;
```

Here we have two types: the root type (I called it `Data`) and another type `Item`. The `Data` type is used in the root XML element `data`.

Ok, now the [marshalling code](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/master/nodejs/demos/user/tests/user-tests.js):

```
    // Create Jsonix context
    var context = new Jsonix.Context([ Mapping ]);

    var data = {
        name : new Jsonix.XML.QName('data'),
        value : {
            "user" : "505723c5750c1fa2177682ed",
            "uri" : "http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items",
            "items" : [ {
                "uri" : "http://localhost:3000/items/1"
            }, {
                "uri" : "http://localhost:3000/items/2"
            } ],
            "info" : "blah."
        }
    };

    var marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    console.log(marshaller.marshalString(data));
```

And here's the XML you get:

```
<data>
    <user>505723c5750c1fa2177682ed</user>
    <uri>http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items</uri>
    <items>
        <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/1</uri>
    </items>
    <items>
        <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/2</uri>
    </items>
    <info>blah.</info>
</data>
```

Links:

- [Jsonix project on GitHub](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix)
- [Jsonix documentation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/JSNX/User+Guide)

---

If you can match your XML with your JSON, check other libraries, for instance [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml2js).

Comment: lexicore. great work.. But bad luck for me.. :( But i cant make a Mapping file. My json can be dynamic. Is there any solution for that.

Comment: @Sreejith With Jsonix not at the moment. I am going to implement mappingless solution, but this won't help you at the moment. But check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27076047/303810), it lists a number of approaches, maybe you'll find something to match your needs. And try `xml2js` which I mentioned.

Comment: @Sreejith Post it as answer (this is OK to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using my library!  I apologize for the delay.  You can achieve that output with this structure:

```
[
    {"user": "505723c5750c1fa2177682ed"},
    {"uri": "http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items"},
    [
        {"items": {"uri": "http://localhost:3000/items/1"}},
        {"items": {"uri": "http://localhost:3000/items/1"}}
    ],
    {"info": "blah."}
]
```

Output:

```
<user>505723c5750c1fa2177682ed</user>
<uri>http://localhost:3000/users/505723c5750c1fa2177682ed/items</uri>
<items>
    <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/1</uri>
</items>
<items>
    <uri>http://localhost:3000/items/1</uri>
</items>
<info>blah.</info>
```